# Delete Statement and Transaction for One row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have only 1 row in a table. Suppose I use following statements

`BEGIN TRANSACTION`

`DELETE FROM mytable` (Now if we check the table, the row will be deleted from table.)

`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` (The row will be again available in table).

My question is, when we ROLLBACK the transaction, from where the SQL Server restores the data or where the data is temporarily held during transaction.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are asking about Microsoft SQL Server ["it depends..."](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/ghost-cleanup-redux/) - can be either just marked as logically deleted - so just a matter of unmarking it, or from the transaction log

Comment: It's not as simple as "the data was first deleted and then put back". It is not actually completely gone, transaction handling is a lot more complex than just an undo step.

Comment: I think conceptually you can think of the data being put back from the transaction log.  However, that may not be what actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

All of the data modifications within the transaction are stored within the transaction log, with additional space also reserved in the log for the undo records, in the event that it has to rollback. Each transaction log has sufficient information within it, to reverse the change it has made, so that it can undo the change if required.

If we take a simple delete operation as an example, the record being deleted is stored inside the transaction log entry of LOP_DELETE_ROWS and with some non-trivial effort you can decode and demonstrate the entire row is within the log entry.

If the transaction is to be rolled back, the undo space reserved in the log is going to be used, and the row would be re-inserted. The reason for the undo reservation of space is to ensure that the transaction log can not be filled up mid transaction, leaving it no space to complete or rollback.